# Selenium test FIDO key as Virtual Authenticator

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have to do login test where the user after inserting the email has to insert the fido2 key and put his fingerprint on the key in order to login.

The thing is that I read online that this can be done using the virtual authenticator but unfortunately I did not manage to make it work, because when it comes to the point where I have to select from the pop up the usb key and do the rest of the process the pop up does not show which I heard is a good sign but I get an error from the application saying that the fido2 is not ok.

At this point I am curious if the FIDO2 configuration is wrong in the virtual authenticator or the virtual authenticator is not working at all.

Does anyone used selenium and fido2 before and encounter this problem with the virtual authenticator ?

If so please let me know .

This is my virtual authenticator :

```
 private VirtualAuthenticator setupVirtualAuthenticator() {
        VirtualAuthenticatorOptions options = new VirtualAuthenticatorOptions();

        options.setTransport(VirtualAuthenticatorOptions.Transport.INTERNAL);
        options.setProtocol(VirtualAuthenticatorOptions.Protocol.CTAP2);

        options.setHasUserVerification(true);
        options.setIsUserVerified(true);
        options.setHasResidentKey(false);

        VirtualAuthenticator authenticator = ((HasVirtualAuthenticator) driver).addVirtualAuthenticator(options);

        return authenticator;
    }
```

and in the test that is the first thing I call is :

```
setupVirtualAuthenticator();
```

Can anyone give me some hints about what am I doing wrong ? Thank you

Comment: Did you follow the instruction provided on this page? https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/virtual_authenticator/

Comment: yes, but it does not work , because it keeps blocking